# Юноша и вьюнош(а)

Tags: этимология, славянизмы

Нередко в книгах, когда автор хочет показать архаичную речь, я встречаю слово "юноша" в странной форме "вьюноша" или "вьюнош". Мне всегда казалось, что это просто шутка - буква В добавляется впереди, чтобы сделать слово похожим на "вьюн". Но встречаю я это слово довольно часто, что заставило меня задуматься: а может, это просто устаревшая форма слова "юноша"?
А как на самом деле?

Comment: На мой вкус такое произношение звучит шуточно-иронично.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Возможно, это протеза, то есть присоединение "лишнего" звука в начале для удобства произношения. Так, например, образовалось слово "восемь" (раньше оно звучало как "осемь", отсюда "осьминог").

Comment: Ещё отец - вотчина.

Answer (score 2):

Слово "вьюноша" или "вьюнош" имеет некоторый архаичный, а сегодня уже и неодобрительно-ироничный оттенок. То же, что юноша (нейтр.).

Answer (score 1):

Обратим внимание на українську мову: рус./**она** - укр./**вона**, рус./**улица** - укр./**вулиця**, рус./**уголь** - укр./**вугілля**, рус./**отечество** - укр./**вітчизна**, рус./**Армения**, **армяне** - укр./**Вірменія**, **вірмени** и др. Судя по всему, как уже указал [[@Серж](/users/1826/%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6)](/users/1826/%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6), добавление **В** перед гласной это какой-то архаизм. Он сохранился в українськой мове, но в русском языке всплывает только в единичном примере - ВЬЮНОША (юноша). Однако никакой "*неодобрительно-ироничный оттенок*" этот архаизм не содержит. Это именно архаизм, потому что в українськой мове много слов, начинающихся на У, О и др. гласные, безо всякой **В**.

Comment: Ещё вспомнилось русское - **вострый** = острый.

Comment: Причем тут "українська мова"?

Answer (score 0):

Фасмер.
вьюни́ца, вью́нош(а) -- народноэтимологические изменения слов цслав. происхождения юне́ц, ю́ноша и т. д.; см. ю́ный; см. также Горяев, Доп.

http://www.slova.ru/article/5402.html